# How to get version of Maven in a Maven property?

Tags: maven

Is it possible to get the version of Maven as a property?

For example, in [this guide](http://takari.io/book/70-testing.html#configuring-the-pom) I have to choose a version of `maven-core` library according to the version of Maven I have installed, but it doesn't say if I should just type whatever version I have installed, or to get it programmatically. I suppose the latter, but can't find a way to do so.

Comment: Why do you need the maven version in a property?

Comment: @khmarbaise I explained that in the question.

Comment: Sorry but you don't.

Comment: @Suseika The reason is provided in the link, but it would be better IMHO to describe in your question as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to dynamically specify dependency versions...

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already is such a property: `maven.version`

The Maven Archiver will even write the value of this property to `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` by default:

```
...
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.5
...
```

See [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html) for details.